# Fulltext Contains does not return rows

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have a row in a table that contains "DS012345" in a column called description
When I use this query:

```
Select * from Tablename where Contains(Description, ' "*012345*" ')
```

This query returns no result.
I have created the unique index, fulltext catalog, I have turned off the Stop Words using the Object Explorer. Still do not know why it does not return that row.
Any suggestion or cause for this?

Thanksl.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `LIKE` instead to do a search.

```
Select * from Tablename where Description LIKE '%012345%'
```

Just does a search where `012345` appears anywhere within the description column.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to specifically use Contains in this scenario

Comment: Ahh I see, apologies I didn't realise Contains was a must :)

Comment: @dkum According to some docs the asterisks only work one way, such as `'"test*"'` not both ways with the asterisks on both sides like `'"*test*"'`. I don't think it works properly for partial searches. Perhaps give this a go and see if the prefixed version works with the one asterisk at the end. E.g. `'"DS*"'`

Comment: Thanks.. Would try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Stop words is the number that it starts to seek for a word in your database..
Fulltext should be used to get the exact word, if you just want a part of the word you should use LIKE %...%.